# How to display a map which contains two values of two different keys?

Tags: json, jq, aws-cli

As part of a shell script I'm writing, I'm querying AWS (cli) to pull information regarding available security group names and ids, like so:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups | jq -r '.SecurityGroups[]'
{
  "IpPermissionsEgress": [
    {
      "IpProtocol": "-1",
      "PrefixListIds": [],
      "IpRanges": [
        {
          "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
        }
      ],
      "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
      "Ipv6Ranges": []
    }
  ],
  "Description": "default VPC security group",
  "IpPermissions": [
    {
      "PrefixListIds": [],
      "FromPort": 80,
      "IpRanges": [
        {
          "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
        }
      ],
      "ToPort": 80,
      "IpProtocol": "tcp",
      "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
      "Ipv6Ranges": [
        {
          "CidrIpv6": "::/0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "PrefixListIds": [],
      "FromPort": 22,
      "IpRanges": [
        {
          "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
        }
      ],
      "ToPort": 22,
      "IpProtocol": "tcp",
      "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
      "Ipv6Ranges": []
    },
    {
      "PrefixListIds": [],
      "FromPort": -1,
      "IpRanges": [
        {
          "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
        }
      ],
      "ToPort": -1,
      "IpProtocol": "icmp",
      "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
      "Ipv6Ranges": []
    }
  ],
  "GroupName": "default",
  "VpcId": "vpc-b3c29bcb",
  "OwnerId": "506490286752",
  "GroupId": "sg-83db2ef7"
}
```

And using `jq`, I'm trying to return a list of maps which displays the info like so:

> GroupName , GroupId

This is what I've tried:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups  | jq -r '.SecurityGroups[] | to_entries[] | [ .GroupName.value , .GroupId.value]'
```

Using the above method returns:

```
[
  null,
  null
]
[
  null,
  null
]
```

In the example, the delimiter is "," but I'd like the displayed output to be like so  (example):

```
"default - sg-abd837s"
```

How can it be done by using `jq`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no need to use `to_entries`:

```
.SecurityGroups[]
| [ .GroupName, .GroupId ]
| join(" - ")
```

produces:

"default - sg-abd837s"

Answer (score 2):

Using string interpolation:

```
.SecurityGroups[] | "\(.GroupName) - \(.GroupId)"
```